# Help with incrementing intergers when looping in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have declared an int e.g. int i;

I have a method that is looped:

```
 public static void NumberUp(int i)
    {
        i++;
        System.Console.WriteLine(i);
...
}
```

although each time the number is returned, it is always 1. Not 1,2,3 and so on..

I would have imagined that "i" increases by one which each run of the method?

Comment: It doesen't, thats a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the variable [by reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx).

```
public static void NumberUp(ref int i)
{
   i++;
   System.Console.WriteLine(i);
   ...
}
```

This, however is bad design, as you now have a method with a side effect on the passed in parameter (which the method name doesn't indicate) - something that can catch other programmers by surprise.

It would be a better design to return the incremented value:

```
public static int NumberUp(ref int i)
{
   return i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Fortunatelly we're not in VB.NET, hence no `byref` here. Cheers :)

Comment: To elaborate: int is a value type in c#, and is copied to the method. Each time you call it, it gets a new copy. if you change it to pass by reference youre method gets a reference to the orignal rather then a copy, and it would work as you expect.

Comment: @Oded: Please get your code right. Your second example still has `byref` instead of `ref` and it contradicts what is said above: (1) it still has a side effect, because the parameter is passed by ref and (2) it returns the old value and only after it increments it.

Comment: There's nothing _intrinsically_ bad about passing by reference. The "return the updated value" is more flexible in this case, true, but it's not necessary in all cases. And it's often desirable to be able to return more than one thing without messing about with returning whole classes.

Comment: @paxdiablo, I disagree, passing by value is preferential to passing by reference. If your function has a complex return type define it.

Comment: I'd prefer not to have to create a whole class just to return an error plus a value (as a simple example). Some may have different opinions, not saying they're wrong, just that I often prefer simple code over the "correct" way :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo:  You can always use one of the Tuple classes (4.0), such as Tuple<T1, T2>

Answer (score 1):

It's doing that because you're passing it by value. That means the variable *within* the function is a *copy* of the original.

If you want changes to reflect back to the *original* variable, you need to pass it by reference, meaning the variable refers to the original rather than a copy. You can use something like:

```
public static void NumberUp (ref int i) {
    i++;
    System.Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to define `NumberUp` like this

```
public static int NumberUp(int number)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(++number);
    return number;
}
```

Then assign the return value in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a value type and not a reference type. As such, `i` inside `NumberUp` is a copy of the parameter you passed in.
If you want the value to be changed outside the method, pass the parameter as reference:

```
public static void NumberUp(ref int i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [reference vs value type](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=reference%20vs%20value%20type). To accomplish what you actually need, you have to pass `i` [by reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

The Method is static but this does not automatically mean the parameter is.
Maybe use a static int in you class as member.

```
class x
{ static int i;
```

Or pass it byRef